# Normal linear system (embeddings into projective space)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

We consider a variety $X$ over $k$. I have a question on an [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_scheme#Geometric_and_algebraic_interpretations_of_normality) from wikipedia deals with interpretations of normality in algebraic geometry. It says:

> An older notion is that a subvariety $X$ of projective space is linearly normal if the linear system giving the embedding is complete. Equivalently, $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is not the linear projection of an embedding $X \subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}_k$ (unless $X$ is contained in a hyperplane $\mathbb{P}^n$). This is the meaning of "normal" in the phrases rational normal curve and rational normal scroll.

By definition a linear system $L$ is complete if there *exist* a divisor $D \subset C$ such that $L= \vert D \vert$.

Recall: $\vert D \vert:= \{ (f) + D \ \vert \ f \in \mathcal{O}_X(D) \}$.

Futhermore a map $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^n$ induced by a divisor $D$ is completly determined by data $\{s_i \in \mathcal{O}(D) \ \vert i=0,1,...,n \}$ and these sections are considered as pullbacks of the canonical generators $X_i$ of $ H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))=kX_0 \oplus kX_1 \oplus ... \oplus kX_n$; i.e. $s_i = f^*X_i$.

Denote by $i_n: X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ the embedding of $X$ into projective space above. Using definition above we can indentify $\vert D \vert$ with projective space $(H^0(X,D) - \{0\})/k^*$.

The definition of completeness of linear system $L$ above is equivalent to the statement the global sections $s_i = i_n^*X_i$, which generate in general  only the linear $k$-subspace $<\pi^*X_i \vert i=0,1,2>_k$ of $k$-space $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D_0))$ for certain divisor $D_0 \subset X$, in case of completeness generate the *whole* $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D_0))$.

**Question**: Why is it equivalent that the subvariety $X$ of projective space $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ is *linearly normal* to the claim that $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is not the *linear projection* of an embedding $X \subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}_k$ (unless $X$ is contained in a hyperplane $\mathbb{P}^n$)? Moreover, can the assumption on $X$ to be a *variety* replaced by $k$-scheme ?

A couple words about the (linear) projection $\mathbb{P}^{n+1} \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$: it's a well known construction: Let $p \in \mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ and $\mathbb{P}^n \cong H \subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ a hyperplane not containing $p$. This induces the projection $\pi_{p,H}: \mathbb{P}^n \dashrightarrow  \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. It's only a rational map,  but a sophisticated choise of $p$ and hyperplane allows that the restriction of $\pi_{p,H}$ to $X$ becomes a morphism.

Ideas: In case of $X$ a variety I think I have a solution.  The problem reduces obviously to following claim: Let $i_{n+1}:X \subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}_k$ defined (compare with my remarks above) by $n+1$ sections /pullbacks of $ X_i \in H^0(\mathbb{P}^{n+1}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n+1}}(1))$: $s_i = f^*X_i$.

**Claim**: if the $s_i$ are *not* linear independent, then $X$ lies in a hyperplane $H \cong \mathbb{P}^n$.

For varieties it’s fine : a map from $X$ to projective space $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ is defined by $x \mapsto [s_0(x) : s_1(x) :... :s_n(x)]$ and if the $s_i$ are not linear independent we obviously can factorize it through a hypersurface. e.g. if $s_n= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i s_i$ then obviously the map factorize through the map $x \mapsto [s_0(x) : s_1(x) :... :s_{n-1}(x)]$.

Now, if we think about the second part of my question we can ask if the *Claim* holds also for $k$-schemes instead of $k$-varieties, we observe that although maps to $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ are still uniquely determined by pullbacks $s_i$, we can’t the morphism $X \to \mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ simply "write down" as $x \mapsto [s_0(x) : s_1(x) :... :s_n(x)]$, that's only a suggestive notation, that is the linear algebra argument as above might be too fishy.

Is the *Claim* for $k$-schemes nevertheless true and which *formal* argument can be used to reason it?

Comment: Have you tried carrying out your linear algebra argument on the level of graded rings?

Comment: @TabesBridges: Let $k[X_0,X_1,...,X_{n+1}]$ the graded ring of $P^{n}$ and we add up the $s_i= f^*X_i$, $i=0,1,...,n$ (we assume that $s_0,..., s_n$ are linear independent, but $s_n= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i s_i$) to a basis of $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D_0))$. Say $m= \dim_k H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D_0))$. We obtain a symetrical algebra $Sym(H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D_0)))$ generated as algeba by $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D_0))= Sym^1(H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D_0)))$. Then the map $X_i \mapsto s_i=f^*X_i$ of graded rings

Comment: factorize over $k[X_0,X_1,...,X_{n}]$ since by assumption $s_0,s_1,..., s_{n+1}$ are not linear independent. Explicitly the factorization map $k[X_0,X_1,...,X_{n+1}] \to k[X_0,X_1,...,X_{n}]$ is $X_i \mapsto X_i$ for $i \le n$ and $X_{n+1} \mapsto \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i X_i$. I think this suffice to obtain the factorization $X \subset P^n =H \subset P^{n+1}$?